# 'function' object has no attribute 'value' when class function is used in Enum values

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, operators

I just want to achieve some extra which is not there in **operator** module of python like `not_contain`. For that I created my own class with the `not_contain` method. I just want to do some more variation and for that I need the class. I am using python3.

```
class UserDefinedOperators:
    def not_contain(self, a, b):
            return a not in b
    def some_other_function(self, a, b):
            some other work here
```

Now I am creating an Enum like this

```
import operator
import enum

class MyOperators(enum.Enum):
    LT = operator.gt
    GT = operator.gt
    NOT_CONTAIN = UserDefinedOperators().not_contain
```

I am having following differences in accessing the Enum value

```
>>> MyOperators
<enum 'MyOperators'>
>>> MyOperators.LT
<MyOperators.LT: <built-in function gt>>
>>> MyOperators.LT.value
<built-in function gt>
>>> MyOperators.LT.name
'LT'
>>> MyOperators.NOT_CONTAIN
<bound method UserDefinedOperators.not_contain of <__main__.UserDefinedOperators object at 0x100cdbeb0>>
>>> MyOperators.NOT_CONTAIN.value
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'value'
>>> MyOperators.NOT_CONTAIN.name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'name'
>>>
```

So with the class function, the Enum shows

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'value'
```

I read on other SO answer that it is getting assigned as function and not Enum attributes that is why it doesn't have `.value` or `.name` attributes. But then built in `operator.lt` and `operator.gt` is also a function then how come it is working fine and have .value and .name properties?

The error does come with normal function not just class function but I want to understand what difference it is in operator module? How can I achieve the same with my class?

Answer (score 1):

Enum uses the presence of the `__dunder__` method `__get__` to determine if an object is a function/class.  Functions and classes created in Python all have a `__get__` method, but built-in functions do not.

To get around this problem you can use the `aenum`<sup>1</sup> module and its `member` function:

```
from aenum import Enum, member
import operator

class UserDefinedOperators:
    #
    @staticmethod
    def not_contain(self, a, b):
            return a not in b


class MyOperators(Enum):
    LT = operator.lt
    GT = operator.gt
    NOT_CONTAIN = member(UserDefinedOperators.not_contain)
```

and in use

```
>>> list(MyOperators)
[
  <MyOperators.LT: <built-in function lt>>,
  <MyOperators.GT: <built-in function gt>>,
  <MyOperators.NOT_CONTAIN: <function UserDefinedOperators.not_contain at 0x7f9c875ed790>>,
  ]
```

Note that I made `not_contain` be a `staticmethod`.  This is appropriate since the `not_contain` method does not require any instance nor class data to do its job.  This also means you do not need to instantiate `UserDefinedOperators` with creating the `NOT_CONTAIN` enum member.

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: I'll point out, too, that a class of nothing but static methods is just a dressed-up dictionary with functions for values.